# c++: create derived object from another derived type

Tags: c++, oop

assumed i have this classes, and the following main:

```
class LabTest
{
private:
    std::string labID;
    bool result;
};
class Person
{
protected:
    std::string name;
    std::string lastName;
    std::string ID;
    std::list<LabTest> testList;
};
class Sick :public Person
{
    //
};
//Encounter represents a person who comes in contact with a verified Sick
class Encounter : public Person
{
    //
};
void main()
{
    std::list<Person*> personList;
    std::list<LabTest*> testList;
}
```

now in case that the Encounter received a positive LabTest result, i need to replace the Encounter from the personList in Sick.
i'd like to write something like it:

```
void updateStatusPerson(Person* person, bool resultLabTest)
{
    if (resultLabTest)
    {
        person = new Sick(/*(Encounter*)person*/);
    }
}
```

that the Person* from Sick type, replace the Person* from Encounter type..
so to implementation this, i added this in Sick class:

```
Sick::Sick(Encounter* encounter) :Person(*(Person*)encounter)
{
    delete encounter;
}
```

Although i implementation of deep copy constructor in Person class (for memory allocation).
actually i got Junk value in the Person* in the personList.
Is there a way to do this? Is there better design for that case?
thanks you all.

Comment: Why is `Sick` a class, and not an attribute of a `Person`?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm because Sick has special attributes and methods that do not belong to a Person class (I didn't add it to the code in the question above)

Answer (score 0):

In `updateStatusPerson`, you are taking a copy of a pointer to `Person` as your first argument. Deletng that pointer will `delete` whatever it points to, assigning to it will, however, not change the value of the memory it was pointing to, buit simply change the address to which it points. This means that the pointer you passed will become invalid, and you have a memory-leak. You can fix that by taking a reference to a pointer to `Person` as your first parameter instead:

```
void updateStatusPerson(Person*& person, bool resultLabTest)
{
    if (resultLabTest)
    {
        person = new Sick(/*(Encounter*)person*/);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help, i changed like your suggesion , and also i move the delete from the Sick's copy  constuctor to updateStatusPerson, and i have to erase and push to the list, and now it's working. thanks you.

Comment: @O_Y Happy to help